# Saving Sprites as Arrays in SFML

Tags: c++, c++17, sfml

All right so I am trying to create a program that draws a picture of A when the user presses A. I havn't gotten anywhere near that far but just so you understand what the end goal is. Anyways I tried to make a function called `DrawKey(string key)` I have it set up with no errors the issue is it's not drawing the sprite. I have no idea where I went wrong please help.

```cpp
static void DrawKey(string key)
    {
        sf::RenderWindow Key(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "A");
        sf::Style::None;
        while (Key.isOpen())
        {
            //Sprites
            map<string, sf::Sprite> Sprite;
            map<string, sf::Texture> Tex;
            sf::Texture ATex;
            ATex.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/A.jpg");
            sf::Texture DTex;
            DTex.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/D.jpg");
            sf::Texture ETex;
            ETex.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/E.jpg");
            sf::Texture QTex;
            sf::Texture STex;
            QTex.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/Q.jpg");
            STex.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/S.jpg");
            sf::Texture WTex;
            WTex.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/W.jpg");
            sf::Texture XTex;
            XTex.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/X.jpg");
            sf::Texture ZTex;
            ZTex.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/Z.jpg");
            sf::Texture EscTex;
            EscTex.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/esc.jpg");
            Tex["A", "D", "E", "Q", "S", "W", "X", "Z", "Esc"] = ATex, DTex, ETex, QTex, STex, WTex, XTex, ZTex, EscTex;
            sf::Sprite ASprite;
            ASprite.setTexture(ATex);
            sf::Sprite DSprite;
            ASprite.setTexture(Tex["D"]);
            sf::Sprite ESprite;
            ASprite.setTexture(Tex["E"]);
            sf::Sprite QSprite;
            ASprite.setTexture(Tex["Q"]);
            sf::Sprite SSprite;
            ASprite.setTexture(Tex["S"]);
            sf::Sprite WSprite;
            ASprite.setTexture(Tex["W"]);
            sf::Sprite XSprite;
            ASprite.setTexture(Tex["X"]);
            sf::Sprite ZSprite;
            ASprite.setTexture(Tex["Z"]);
            sf::Sprite EscSprite;
            ASprite.setTexture(Tex["Esc"]);
            Sprite["A", "D", "E", "Q", "S", "W", "X", "Z", "Esc"] = ASprite, DSprite, ESprite, QSprite, SSprite, WSprite, XSprite, ZSprite, EscSprite;


            // Process events
            sf::Event event;
            while (Key.pollEvent(event))
            {
                // Close window: exit
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    Key.close();
            }
            // Clear screen
            Key.clear(sf::Color::Transparent);
            Key.draw(Sprite[key]);
            Key.display();
        }
```

Yes i know I can make it write a letter I want it as a image.
Thanks for your help i'm kind of new to all of this.

Comment: "I have it set up with no errors the issue is it's not drawing the sprite." I understand what you mean (no compilation errors) - but it's still a funny sentence. "There are no errors, except that it doesn't work."

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what language can you do this comma-separated-indexing like you're doing here? I've seen it on SO a few times in the past week and wondering where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma operator in C++ is a common trip-up point for a lot of beginners. It evaluates all expressions in it (and takes into account their side effects) but only returns the right-most value.

```
Sprite["A", "D", "E", "Q", "S", "W", "X", "Z", "Esc"] = ASprite, DSprite, ESprite, QSprite, SSprite, WSprite, XSprite, ZSprite, EscSprite;
```

is equivalent (since none of the operands to the various comma expressions have side effects) to:

```
Sprite["Esc"] = EscSprite;
```

I'm curious if hitting `Esc` draws the `EscSprite` as expected.

---

You make ask, "Well why doesn't the program crash when I try to access the "A" key from the map?

```
Key.draw(Sprite[key]);
```

The answer is that the `[]` operator on a `std::map` will retrieve the value at that key, unless that key does not exist, in which case it will default construct the value and return *that*.

Comment: is there a way i could do what I am trying to do with the commas. Just trying to make the code more concise.

Comment: You have patterns in your strings that could be looped. But you're also loading from file several times on each key press, and discarding all but one of those file loads. You could load from only the file you need in this function, or better yet, make this map a static global data structure that is initialized once in some `init` function.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems to your code from what I read :

#### Few reasons it doesn't work

**Comma error**

You seem to use the comma to write your intent as you would in another language here :

```
Tex["A", "D", "E", "Q", "S", "W", "X", "Z", "Esc"] = ATex, DTex, ETex, QTex, STex, WTex, XTex, ZTex, EscTex;
```

You cannot use the comma this way in c++. Here you use the built-in comma operator. As specified here :
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

> In a comma expression E1, E2, the expression E1 is evaluated, its result is discarded (although if it has class type, it won't be destroyed until the end of the containing full expression), and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression E2 begins (note that a user-defined operator, cannot guarantee sequencing) (until C++17).

Here each expressions followed by a comma will do nothing, until the last parameter which will be used, so your expression is only `Tex["Esc"] = EscTex;`.

The same goes later with the line

```
Sprite["A", "D", "E", "Q", "S", "W", "X", "Z", "Esc"] = ASprite, DSprite, ESprite, QSprite, SSprite, WSprite, XSprite, ZSprite, EscSprite;
```

Later, when you try to use Tex["A"] for example, it will create a new empty texture as you never specified any.

**Copy pasting error**

Each `setTexture` function is called on `ASprite`, I don't think it is your intent here.

#### Diverse advices

**Initialize once**

You should never load from the same file in your rendering (or any) loop as it is a very costly operation. Even the sprite creation can be done only once, avoiding the creation cost each frames.

**Consistent norm**

You have a few variables that start with an upper case letter, some don't, try to be consistent here. as specified in the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#nl8-use-a-consistent-naming-style)

**Other**

```
sf::Style::None; //<This line doesn't do anything
```

#### Edit

To solve the comma error the c++ way, use the initializer list of the map :

```
map<string, sf::Texture> Tex;
Tex = {
    { "A", ATex },
    { "B", BTex },
    { "C", CTex },
    // ...
};
```